# Expected Value of Changing Data

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

We have an 30 grenades. 1/3 grenades are useless. One soldier throw grenades at every 30 seconds in 3 minutes (i.e. throw 6 grandes). What is the expected value of all grenades successfully explode?

Comment: What have you come up with?

Comment: I am think about it should be : 20/30*20+19/29*19+... but it is wrong i think. My friend says 20/30*20+19/29*19+...-10*10/30-9*9/29...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of the grenades which will explode. We then have that $X$ is a random variable which distributes [hypergeometrically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), with parameters $N=30,K=20,n=6$. The expected value is then

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=n \frac{K}{N}=6 \cdot \frac{20}{30}=4$$

grenades.

Comment: When you throw a grenade the grenade number is changed. I think you did it wrong. I don't think so it is that easy because it was my exam question.

Comment: "... the hypergeometric distribution is a discrete probability distribution that describes the probability of k successes in n draws, *without* replacement..." - Wikipedia

Comment: I think that it was that easy :( http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricDistribution.html . Wiki is not clear but wolfram is clear.